# About the feedback of sql diagram

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I actually need some feedback on the tables since my goal is to have
only the admin who can add the users and add files to the users. An admin can login and select either add users, add files for the users.Only the users who can login and download files.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're missing a `USER_ROLES` table (primary key: `UserID`,`RoleID`).  The FK from `Files` would be to `USER_ROLES`, not `ROLE`.  Also, you should be consistent in naming tables as either singular or plural nouns.  (I prefer plural).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I've made some changes on users_roles table and the only changes on the users table is only the userid in pk since I don't need the foreign key in userid.